# Where are clap macros coming from if they are not being imported?

Tags: rust, clap

In the following code snippet, I'm not importing the macros clap and arg but they're still available to the code. Where are they coming from?

```
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
struct Arguments {
    #[clap(short, long)]
    first_part: Option<String>,
    #[arg(short, long)]
    second_part: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Arguments::parse();
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not macros, but [attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html).

The confusion comes because `derive` is also an attribute, not a macro. Only that some derive implementations are implemented as macros. Remember that normal macros are recognized by the `!` not by `#`, such as `println!`.

About where these attributes come from? Well, attributes are never imported, these [derive macro helper attributes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#derive-macro-helper-attributes) are parsed either directly by any macro that may be in effect. Yes, this means that these attributes are not scoped and could, in theory, conflict between several crates. It hasn't happened that I know of, yet.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thank you. For future reference, for version 4.0.32, these helper attributes are "defined", or better, identified and attributed meaning in clap_derive/src/attr.rs ClapAttr::parse_all()